# How to use Sails req.param function to retrieve and update a record

Tags: parameters, sails.js

I am trying to use the **req.param.** function in sails 1.0 in vain. I cant seam to retrieve a record values and pre load them on the edit form so that I can update record. Below are my code snippet.

routes

`'GET /organization/:id':       { action: 'organization/view-organization-edit' },`
`'PUT /api/v1/organization/edit-organization/': { action: 'organization/edit-organization' },`

below is where I trigger the action on my ajax form

```
 <td>
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <span class="float-sm-left">
                                  <a style="width: 70px" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-info" href="/organization/<%= organization.id %>">Edit </a>
                                </span>
                               
                                  <form class= "d-inline" action="" method="post">
                                    <input style="width: 70px" type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger">
                                  </form>                             
                            </div> 
......
```

this gives me the url **http://localhost:1337/organization/1**

**View Edit Action**

```
module.exports = {


  friendlyName: 'View organization edit',


  description: 'Display "Organization edit" page.',


  exits: {

    success: {
      viewTemplatePath: 'pages/organization/edit-organization'
    }

  },


  fn: async function (req,res) {

   console.log(this.req.id);

  var organization = await Organization.findOne({ id:this.req.id });// **here is where the error occurs**

    // Respond with view.
    return {
      organizationData: organization, 
      //id:organization.id

    };

  }


};
```

**Edit Action**

```
    friendlyName: 'Update organization',
  
  
    description: 'Update organization.',
  
    inputs: {
      Org_Name: {
        type: 'string'
      },
        
      Org_Level:  {
        type: 'string'        
      }
  
    },  
  
    exits: {
      success: {
        description: "Successful",
      },
    },

  
  
  fn: async function ({Org_Name,Org_Level}) {

    console.log("We are in update function");

    //var org_name= req.body.Org_Name;
    //var org_level=req.body.Org_Level;
    //var id= req.param.id;
    
    console.log(this.req.me.Org_Name);
    console.log(this.req.me.Org_Level);
    console.log(this.req.me.id );
    //console.log(id);

    var valuesToSet = {Org_Name,Org_Level};

    await Organization.updateOne({id: this.req.me.id })
    .set(valuesToSet);

   /* Organization.update({id},{org_name,org_level}).exec(function(err){
        if(err){
          res.send(500, {err: "some error occured"});
        }
        
    
      });*/
    
      return true;  
    }
  
  
  };
```

**Edit Page**

````
 <div id="account-overview" v-cloak>
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <ol class="breadcrumb">
                    <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="/organization" >Organizations</a></li>
                    <li class="breadcrumb-item active">Edit</li>
                </ol>                
            </div>
            <h5>Updating: <%= organizationData.Org_Name%></h5>
            <ajax-form method= "put" action="editOrganization" :form-data="formData" >
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-sm-6">                   
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="Org_Name">Church Organization</label>
                      <input class="form-control" id="Org_Name" name="Org_Name" type="text"  :class="[formErrors.Org_Name ? 'is-invalid' : '']" Value=" <%= organizationData.Org_Name%>" autocomplete="name" >
                      <div class="invalid-feedback" v-if="formErrors.Org_Name">Please enter your church Organization.</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="Org_Level">Organization level</label>
                        <input class="form-control" id="Org_Level" name="Org_Level" type="text"  :class="[formErrors.Org_Level ? 'is-invalid' : '']"  Value=" <%= organizationData.Org_Level%>" autocomplete="name">
                        <div class="invalid-feedback" v-if="formErrors.Org_Level"> Please enter your Organization Level</div>
                      </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                          <cloud-error v-if="cloudError === 'emailAlreadyInUse'">There is already an Organization using that Name.</cloud-error>
                          <cloud-error v-if="cloudError"></cloud-error>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                          <div class="form-group text-right">
                            <a class="btn btn-outline-info" href="/Organization">Cancel</a>
                            <ajax-button type="submit"  class="btn btn-dark">Submit</ajax-button>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                </div> 
              </ajax-form>
            
        </div>```
````

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

```
In async function you can define req and use it or you can just say this.req.param('id');

  fn: async function ({Org_Name,Org_Level}) {
    let req = this.req;
    let res = this.res;

    console.log("We are in update function");

    //var org_name= req.body.Org_Name;
    //var org_level=req.body.Org_Level;
    //var id= req.param.id;
    
    console.log(this.req.me.Org_Name);
    console.log(this.req.me.Org_Level);
    console.log(this.req.me.id );
    //console.log(id);

    var valuesToSet = {Org_Name,Org_Level};

    await Organization.updateOne({id: this.req.me.id })
    .set(valuesToSet);

   /* Organization.update({id},{org_name,org_level}).exec(function(err){
        if(err){
          res.send(500, {err: "some error occured"});
        }
        
    
      });*/
    
      return true;  
    }
  
  
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Log your req Variable and check if there is an object with name "body" and "params".
If Yes you need to fetch it using req.body or req.allParams()